# When I should use multiple 2048x2048 sprite sheets rather then a single 4096x4096 sprite sheet

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm working on a game that will be using 2D sprite-sheets for NPC animations. I'm having a hard time deciding on which one to use: 1 big 4096x4096 sprite-sheet or multiple 2048x2048 for each character.

If I go with the sprite sheet size 2048 option I would have to switch sprite-sheets back and forth almost every second for different animation states (and that's for each NPC character on screen). Considering there usually will be more than 1 type of NPC rendering on-screen that sounds like a lot of processing power.

There is also the aspect ratio of the mobile device. I'm planning to release for mobile devices as well as PC. Online research shows 2048x2048 is the safe spot but the year is 2020 and handheld devices are more powerful than ever. Are we really still limited with 2048x2048 on modern devices?

So which one would perform better on PC and is there even a choice for mobile devices such as using the OpenGL graphics library for loading and rendering large bitmap? if not I will have to reduce sprite resolutions for the mobile version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want, in 2020 we still have a problem with texture size, but now this more about memory saving and compressing textures, not about hardware capability of 4096 texture size.

### Hardware Capability

About hardware, most of OpenGL ES 2.0 devices on android have limitations for 2048x2048 texture, you can check the number of devices there -https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html.

For iOS last devices which did not support 4096x4096 textures -

- iPhone 3GS
- iPhone 4
- iPad

The newer devices of iOS facility supporting 4096x4096 textures.

### Memory and compressing

The difference between 4096 and 2048 texture four times, and for all mobile games this more than they need for not very detailed models. And atlases this is really necessary? Because you need to remember about a useful part of this giant texture for the current scene.

For example, a PVR compressor only supports textures up to 2048, not 4096. And this is the most used type of texture compressing on mobile devices.